# In pytorch does methods on `Tensors` like for instance `cos` do a `deep_copy` or a `clone`?

Tags: python, pytorch, copy, deep-copy

Here is a little code that helps explaining the question

```py
import torch
from torch import Tensor

class TensorSub(Tensor):
  def __init__(self):
    Tensor.__init__(self)

sub = TensorSub()
sub2 = sub.cos()

print(sub)
print(sub2)
```

this gives the following output :

```
TensorSub([])
TensorSub([])
```

In order to have a type `TensorSub` for `sub2`, it feels like the `cos` function does a deep copy of `sub` and then apply the `cos` transformation to it. I am trying to understand this behavior.

---

I tried overloading the `__copy__` and `__deepcopy__` function as follow

```py
class TensorSub(Tensor):
  def __init__(self):
    Tensor.__init__(self)
  def __copy__(self):
    print("copy")
  def __deepcopy__(self, memo):
    print("deepcopy")
```

but this would not print any additional things. I also went into the actual code of Pytorch for the function `cos` and `Tensor` but, I couldn't find anything interesting because those are just calls to some C code.

Comment: This issue page that suggests improving Tensor subclassing might contain some interesting info. https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/22402